# mysql change socket to xampp socket

Tags: mysql, xampp

when I type '**mysql**' to the terminal I an error with the /tmp/mysql.sock socket

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

but when I type '**ps -ax|grep mysql**' and find the socket its different then in the error message

```
--socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

how can I have mysql connect to the socket above?

Comment: You can create `$HOME/.my.cnf` as a local options file. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html  and set the socket client optoin.

Comment: how do I do this? I'm new with mysql

Comment: With a text editor, create a text file in your home directory called `.my.cnf`. Per the documentation, its contents in the `[client]` section should be `socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`